# WordPress media querying?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a WordPress 4.9.2 installation for a project which uses a custom gallery. What I would like to do is organize media by folders (which there are a few plugins for) and then query that media by folder/category so I can use it for the gallery. The approach I have found using web searches suggests you put the media inside of posts as attachments and then query those. This seems very unintuitive to me from the perspective of a user trying to change the gallery content. Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: 1. you can try to change that plugin functions to make upload them into differ directories( no recommended, because after modifyingyou can't update plugins, or after plugins updates you'll loose all changes ). 2. the plugin may have some hooks, which you can use for changing upload folder for them( I don't think, you'll find some hooks to change directories )

Comment: The plugin is not the issue, grabbing the media is. I don't think there is a call to get all media and filter it similar to get_posts or is there?

Comment: so, you don't want to organize folder by plugins, which uploads media

Comment: No I want to be able to organize media by folders/categories so I am then able to retrieve them via the WordPress API. Do you know what I mean?